# Babel outputting junk after upgrade from Node 12 to 14

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, babeljs

on node 12, the transpiled js looks like so:

```
module.exports=function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var o=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,r),o.l=!0,o.exports}return r.........
```

on node 14 it looks like this:

```
(()=>{var e={1910:e=>{"use strict";e.exports={i8:"1.7.6"}},1427:e=>{"use strict";e.exports=JSON.parse('{"services":{"dynamodb":{"operations":{"batchGetItem":{"request_descriptors":{"RequestItems":{"get_keys":true,"rename_to":"table_names"}},"response_parameters":["ConsumedCapacity"]},"batchWriteItem":{"request_descriptors":{"RequestItems":{"get_keys":true,"rename_to":"table_names"}},
```

I have absolutely no idea what this is...

my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        // Don't emit; allow Babel to transform files.
        "noEmit": true,
        "target":"ES2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2016", "es2017.object", "es2017.string"],
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization":false,
        "outDir": "js",
        "resolveJsonModule": true
      },
      "exclude": ["cdk.out", "__tests__", "lib/authorizer/*"],
      "include": ["lib/**/*"]
}
```

and my babel config looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
        ['@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: '14'
                }
            }]
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'
    ]
};
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "swa-cdk-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "swa-cdk-app": "bin/swa-cdk-app.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build && webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "cdk": "cdk",
    "lint": "eslint \"./**/*.ts\" -f codeframe -c .eslintrc.js --fix",
    "synth": "cdk synth",
    "deploy": "cdk deploy --role-arn arn:aws:iam::${bamboo_sts_accountId}:role/cloud-services/pipeline-elevated-access --require-approval never",
    "start": "cdk synth --no-staging > template.yml && sam local start-api",
    "test": "source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm use && tsc && jest --coverage --testResultsProcessor jest-sonar-reporter"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "1.89.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@pact-foundation/pact": "^9.15.0",
    "@serverless/event-mocks": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/jest-when": "^2.7.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.164",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "aws-cdk": "1.89.0",
    "aws-sdk-mock": "^5.0.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.2",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.2",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^3.3.0",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "jest-when": "^3.0.1",
    "mocked-env": "^1.3.2",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "sinon": "^9.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "webpack": "^5.22.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "6.1.0",
    "readdirp": "2.2.1",
    "zip-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-kms": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sqs": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.89.0",
    "@aws-cdk/region-info": "1.89.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.64",
    "@types/bunyan": "^1.8.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.784.0",
    "aws-xray-sdk": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "axios-oauth-client": "^1.3.0",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.14",
    "cdk-constants": "^3.0.3",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.6.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.32"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "reports",
    "reportFile": "test-report.xml",
    "indent": 4
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
      "pre-push": "npm run test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to know what it is? Does your code still work after compiling?

Comment: It is lambda code, the handler `export const handler = async (event: any): Promise<any> => {` isn't found.  So no, code does not work after compiling.

Comment: Did you upgrade anything else? That looks a lot more like a Webpack change than a Node 12 vs 14 change. Maybe you have Webpack installed globally and your different Node versions have a different version?